# Java Android: Retrieving Podcast iTunes Reviews

Tags: java, rss, itunes, podcast

I want to create an Android application that:

1. allows a user to add their RSS Feed from a Podcast,
2. capture all the reviews from iTunes from all around the world into one place.

How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question doesn't quite suit the Q&A format that Stack Overflow is built for. 1) It's against Stack Overflow's policy to ask for tools and libraries and 2) your question is too broad to be answered in a meaningful way according to Stack Overflow's policy. Have a look at the [ask] page if you are interested to learn more about this. Open and opinion based questions like this are surely welcome on http://reddit.com/r/programming for example. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.